# Clicking multiple links with the same link text using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get my program *(written in `python`)* to open multiple links at the same time. I can open one link – but when I change my command from `find_element_by_link_text` to `find_elements_by_link_text` it doesn't work.

For context, I'm trying to open all links on the page with the name `'Annual Report'`.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import options



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://webb-site.com/')

search = driver.find_element_by_name('code')

search.click()

search.send_keys("1830")

search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Financials')

element.click()

    
element = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Annual Report')

element.click()
```

Here's my error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

As I said above. By removing the s in 'elements' it works fine but only opens the first 'Annual Report'.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'` error due to click on a list object. If you want to click multiple items then use a for loop.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://webb-site.com/')

search = driver.find_element_by_name('code')

search.click()

search.send_keys("1830")

search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Financials')

element.click()


element = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Annual Report')
# print(element)
# print(len(element))
# element.click()
for c in element:
    c.click()
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you! I'll have to have a proper look at what you have done.

Comment: I will warn that if these were links (and not triggers to download files) you're likely to run into stale element errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `click` to a list object.

The object `element` in the last line:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Annual Report')
```

is a list.

When you call `find_elements` you get in return a list.

Just change it to:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Annual Report')
```

**Edit**

As @Samsul added, to click on all the elements you'll need to loop through the list.